# how to send json using wt?

Tags: c++, json, wt

I'm trying a C++ framework for web development - Wt (WebToolkit). 
I want to extract data from text fields, create json-object and send it to the server by POST.

```
void LoginForm::sendLogInRequest()
{
   Json::Object data;
   data["username"] = usernameTextEdit->text();
   data["password"] = passwordTextEdit->text();
}
```

then I want to send data. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Wt::Http::Client that can post that data for you. The manual has a usage example.